# Trying to Prove Linear Independence through a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to prove , given the ODE : $y''' +\sqrt{x-1}y' +ln(sinx)y=\frac{cosx}{x-3}$. At the start of the question , I've been given 3  initial conditions - $y(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1 , y'(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0 , y''(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1 $
I've proved through Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem for high order ODE that with the initial conditions the ODE had a single solution. Now I need to prove this ODE has 3 linear independent solutions:
$y_1(x) , y_2(x) , y_3(x)$ through $(5,7)$. I've been trying to get to value of $ y'(5) , y''(5)$ so that I'll be able to have a Wronskian(that uses the initial conditions)  that unequal $0$ to prove linear independent but from there I'm at a dead end and I'm not sure it's the right way at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the function multiplying $y$ in the ODE is $\ln(|\sin x|)$, so that the problem I mentioned in my comment is not an issue, you can find three linearly independent solutions to the ODE passing through the point $(5,7)$ if you choose the following initial conditions:

1. $y(5)=7$, $y'(5)=0$, $y''(5)=0$;
2. $y(5)=7$, $y'(5)=1$, $y''(5)=0$;
3. $y(5)=7$, $y'(5)=0$, $y''(5)=1$.